# Create Diagram - 4 blank horizontal lines in a row - Labels underneath w/lines or arrows pointing

Tags: diagrams

So I want to draw a diagram explaining names of digit places ('hundreds'  'tens' 'ones'). I want blank lines with these labels underneath. I'm thinking qtree might be an idea (4 top branches being the blank lines with 1 branch coming off each for the labels).

I am curious is anyone knows an easier way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\HuTeOn{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance= 0.5cm and 1cm]
  \node (h) {\rule{1.5cm}{0.4pt}};
  \node[right= of h] (t) {\rule{1.5cm}{0.4pt}};
  \node[right= of t] (o) {\rule{1.5cm}{0.4pt}};
  \node[below = of h] (nh) {hundreds};
  \node[below = of t] (nt) {tens};
  \node[below = of o] (no) {ones};
  \foreach \i in {h,t,o}
    \draw[->] (n\i) -- (\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\HuTeOn

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey there. Thanks a lot Gonzalo! That is exactly what I wanted to do! I've never used the \newcommand function before so that was interesting to see. Many interesting things in there actually! Thanks again!